# ngxs selectively serialize properties in array

Tags: angular, ngxs

I have an AccountState which stores a list of accounts. The AccountState must be serialized to local storage so I use the [Storage Plugin](https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/plugins/storage).

However I do not want to serialize each property of the accounts. For example I want to serialize the username but not the password.

Right now I import the Storage plugin like this:

```
NgxsStoragePluginModule.forRoot({
    key: [
        'account.accounts',
        'account.accounts.username' // <-- not working as accounts is an array not an object
    ]
})
```

So can I define that the array must be serialized with the `username` property but not with the `password` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no way to do that through configuration alone. You can, however, provide your own `StorageEngine` and modify the data there.

```
import { NgxsStoragePluginModule, StorageEngine, STORAGE_ENGINE } from '@ngxs/storage-plugin';

export class MyStorageEngine implements StorageEngine {
    get length(): number {
        // Your logic here
    }

    getItem(key: string): any {
        // Your logic here
    }

    setItem(key: string, val: any): void {
        // remove undesired values here
        let state = JSON.parse(val)
        state.accounts.accounts.forEach(acc => delete acc.password);
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(state));
    }

    removeItem(key: string): void {
        // Your logic here
    }

    clear(): void {
        // Your logic here
    }
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        NgxsModule.forRoot([]),
        NgxsStoragePluginModule.forRoot()
    ],
    providers: [
        {
        provide: STORAGE_ENGINE,
        useClass: MyStorageEngine
        }
    ]
})
export class MyModule {}
```

Though, I wouldn't really reccomend this approach, since it will cost a lot of overhead because of the additional (de)serialization.

Another way would be to introduce a self-written plugin which replaces the StoragePlugin and removes the undesired values before they are serialized.

Comment: I was afraid this was the case. A custom plugin would be the nice. Maybe extending the current plugin with a PR supporting this use case would also be an option. Thanks for your time!